# monitoring a process each 1 sec and directing output to a file

Tags: io-redirection, htop

I have a task in which I have to analyze a file transfer between a ftp client and a server.

I know about `htop` command.

If the file transfer takes 15 secs, then I want the `htop` command to run each second untill the file transfer is finished and direct the output to a file so that I can analyze the process. But I cannot think of any method which can get `htop` running each second.

Also, the output of `htop` command prints is not in human-readable form.

Comment: You can use ``watch`` command.

Comment: Can I use it to store the output in file

Answer (score 1):

First off be sure that there isn't an easier way to get the information you want there are a lot of other tools out there that may work better, and htop doesn't go to files well. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534591/htop-output-to-human-readable-file although there is a kludge here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/726333/how-to-save-htop-output-to-file if you can't find something.

What is it in htop that you can't get out of `ps` or some of the other tools designed for command line output and parsing?

Then write a script something like this (untested):

```
#!/bin/bash

my_log="ftp_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).log"
$(command to start the ftp 2>&1 >> "$my_log")& 

my_pid="$!"
sleep 15
still_there=1
while [[ $still_there -gt 0 ]]
do
    if [[ $(ps ax | grep $my_pid | grep -v grep) ]] # If your PID is still in the process table
    then
        # Insert monitoring stuff in here that > to $my_log
        still_there=1
    else
        still_there=0
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Each use of `>` truncates the output file and writes afresh. Perhaps you meant `>>` to append to the output file?

Comment: No. $my_log gets a new name every time you run it (assuming you don't run it more than once a second), so it's a new log file for each run.

Comment: Inside the while loop

Comment: You're right. Cranial flatulence.